# How to rename buttons in Asp.Net Core Kendo Grid filter?

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I try to change filter buttons in Asp.Net Core Kendo Grid, but it works only for operators:

```
.Filterable(filterable => filterable
  .Extra(true)
  .Messages(msg => msg.Info("Text1").Filter("Text2").Clear("Text3"))
  .Operators(operators => operators.ForString(str =>
    str.Clear().StartsWith("Text4").EndsWith("Text5").Contains("Text6")))
)
```

So I can see Text4, Text5, Text6, but Text1, Text2, Text3 are not visible and retain their old meaning.

What could be the problem?

Asp.Net Core 2.2, Kendo UI v2018.2.516

Comment: you are missing a dot before Clear(

Comment: @FrozenButcher, it's copypaste error, fix it. Problem with Text1, Text2, Text3 persists